# The Giant MVVMLight ViewModelLocator

Tags: mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I have a Main project A which has many dependencies like Project B, Project C etc... which are all assemblies/dll. Currently I have a ViewModelLocator in the ProjectA.App.xaml. This is the MVVMLight recommended way. The ViewModelLocator works fine but my problem is it is giant with all the ViewModel references from ProjectB, ProjectC etc... and it is hard to maintain.

I'm looking for a solution to segregate the ViewModelLocator to each projects ProjectB, ProjectC etc... and have their own ViewModelLocators. I also want to remove the global reference of ViewModelLocator which is the MVVMLight recommended way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use inversion of control. Other than that, your question is too broad. Close-voting.

Comment: I prefer coupling the View and ViewModel declaratively through ViewModelLocator. Using IoC to inject ViewModel to the View can be done in the code behind of the XAML view, but it is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a single viewmodel locator, I created separate viewmodel locator for each module/project.